# What am I doing wrong with this .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$    index.php?pageLevel1=$1&pageLevel2=$2&pageLevel3=$3 [L,R=301]
```

When I access my website using http://www.domain.com/testpage/ it gives me the 404 Not Found error. What am I doing wrong?

PS: currently the index.php files just echo the pageLevel1, pageLevel2 and pageLevel3 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the leading slash from Rewrite pattern

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?pageLevel1=$1&pageLevel2=$2&pageLevel3=$3 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of, I don't know why are you using the 301 redirection at all? If you want to accept all characters in the url you just need to have a catch-all rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [L]
```

If you want to catch the parameters like you defined, the rewrite rules can be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)$ index.php?pageLevel1=$1&pageLevel2=$2&pageLevel3=$3 [L]
```

**UPDATE:**

The completed rules in your case (three page levels), with URL slugs which accepts letters and numbers can be like:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?pageLevel1=$1&pageLevel2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?pageLevel1=$1&pageLevel2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?pageLevel1=$1&pageLevel2=$2&pageLevel3=$3 [L]
```

This way you can access pages like:

```
www.domain.com/test
www.domain.com/test/another-test
www.domain.com/test/another-test/new-level
```